# How to access a computer connected to LAN via another computer?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, pfsense, proxmox

I have the following network configuration:

[image: network-diagram]

I wan to able to access the laptop through the entire network, I can't connect it to the switch directly because of physical constraints (there are more reasons, unimportant to the question). I want to avoid bridging the laptop port to the VM to keep things simple in pfSense. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

**Update: fixed WAN diagram**

Comment: what is that empty box above laptop? `can't connect it to the switch directly` what else is connected to that switch, as shown, it's an absolutely pointless piece of equipment

Comment: Does `the entire network` refers to what connects to the switch?  Is `pfSense VM` the default gateway? Most likely `Proxmox Server` would need to "join" `the network` (if it hasn't already), and your DHCP server (`pfSense`?) would need to annouce an extra route for `Laptop` that uses `PS` as the gateway.

Comment: @JaromandaX the empty box above the laptop indicates another ethernet port on the proxmox machine. All devices on the network are connected to the switch (either directly or via another switch in between), I didn't show those devices since they don't matter to my question.

Comment: Another option would be to DNAT (which makes the IP of `PS` in `the network` / on the bridge "represent" `Laptop`).

Comment: Oh, so the Proxmox server has at least 3 NICs - personally, I'd bridge LAN and *empty box*

Comment: @TomYan yes the `entire network` connects to the pfSense VM via the switch shown in the diagram, and yes this pfSense VM is the default gateway. How do I go about the "join" procedure you mention?

Comment: It's weird that you have two NICs enslaved to the bridge and they are connected to the same switch. (Even more strangely, they are labeled "WAN" and "NIC", instead of some load balancing / failover pair, which makes little sense to me.)

Comment: @JaromandaX, so this bridge would be made on the proxmox host and no changes to the pfSense VM?

Comment: @TomYan It seems like I've made a mistake for the WAN port, let me update the diagram.

Comment: "Join" really just means assign an IP on the bridge (that belongs to the same IP subnet of `the network`). You might have already done so unless you do not want `the network` to have access to `PS`.

Comment: But indeed, unless you want to isolate `the network` from `Laptop` or so, there's not much reason not to just enslave the whitebox-NIC to the bridge so that `Laptop` simply joins `the network`. You shouldn't need any changes made in pfSense.

Comment: @JaromandaX New bridge? What / why a new bridge?

Comment: @JaromandaX The thing I *wasn't sure* is that whether `WAN` and `NIC` are enslaved to different bridge*s* (because in the diagram they are somehow sticking to each other without a gap). Hopefully they are because yes that's pretty much the only way the whole setup would make some sense. And the reason I asked is because you said earlier to bridge LAN and "whitebox" together but then you said "a new bridge". (WAN and LAN are almost certainly already bridge slaves because that's how the pfSense VM can use them with a tap, and the diagram mentioned `bridges`.)

Comment: @TomYan I wasn't thinking straight, realised you were right :p